# Adicionar campo customizado a taxonomia do wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomia

Estou dando a manutenção em um site em Wordpress na qual há uma página chamada "Serviços" e por isso há também a "Categoria de Serviços", em certa página do site, esses serviços são listados dentro de cada categoria.

Estou tentando adicionar um novo campo para "Categoria de Serviços", a "ordenação", para que o cliente possa escolher qual será a ordem em que será listada as categorias e seus serviços no formato 0 para primeiro, 1 para segundo e assim por diante.

Pois bem, vi que foi criada uma Taxonomia para tal pagina porém eu não consigo fazer exibir o campo adicional desejado. Segue o código da taxonomia:

```
function taxonomiaCategoriaServico() {

$rotulosCategoriaServico = array(
                                    'name'              => 'Categorias de Servico',
                                    'singular_name'     => 'Categoria de Servico',
                                    'search_items'      => 'Buscar categorias de Servico',
                                    'all_items'         => 'Todas categorias de Servico',
                                    'parent_item'       => 'Categoria de Servico pai',
                                    'parent_item_colon' => 'Categoria de Servico pai:',
                                    'edit_item'         => 'Editar categoria de Servico',
                                    'update_item'       => 'Atualizar categoria de Servico',
                                    'add_new_item'      => 'Nova categoria de Servico',
                                    'new_item_name'     => 'Nova categoria',
                                    'menu_name'         => 'Categorias de Servico',
                                );

$argsCategoriaServico       = array(
                                    'hierarchical'      => true,
                                    'labels'            => $rotulosCategoriaServico,
                                    'show_ui'           => true,
                                    'show_admin_column' => true,
                                    'query_var'         => true,
                                    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'categoria-servico' ),
                                );

register_taxonomy( 'categoriaServico', array( 'servico' ), $argsCategoriaServico );
```

}

Já tentei colocar de tudo dentro do label, já vi a documentação no codex na página do Wordpress e também não consegui.

Segue como eu chamo no template para mostrar as informações.

```
<?php
                    $conteudoTaxonomias = get_terms( 'categoriaServico', '' );
                    foreach ($conteudoTaxonomias as $conteudoTaxonomia):
                            $foto = $conteudoTaxonomia->description; ?>
                            <div class="col-md-6 serv" style="background: url(<?php echo "$foto"; ?>) no-repeat;">
                                <div class="lente" id="diminuir1">

                                </div>

                                <div class="conteudo">
                                    <h3><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $conteudoTaxonomia->name;?></h3>


                                    <ul>
                                        <?php
                                            $servicos = new WP_Query(array(
                                                'post_type'         => 'servico',
                                                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                                                'tax_query'         => array(
                                                                                array(
                                                                                    'taxonomy' => 'categoriaServico',
                                                                                    'field'    => 'slug',
                                                                                    'terms'    => $conteudoTaxonomia->slug
                                                                                )
                                                                            )
                                                )
                                            );
                                            while ( $servicos->have_posts() ) : $servicos->the_post();
                                        ?>
                                        <li><h3>|  &nbsp<?php the_title(); ?></h3></li>

                                        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

                                    </ul>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                    <?php
                    endforeach;
                ?>
```

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai definir os campos fora da função de registrar a taxonomia, usando as actions [`{taxonomy}_edit_form_fields`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_edit_form_fields/) e/ou [`{taxonomy}_add_form_fields`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_add_form_fields/)

```
add_action( "categoriaServico_edit_form_fields", array( $this, 'exibe_campo' ), 10, 2 )
add_action( "categoriaServico_add_form_fields", array( $this, 'exibe_campo' ), 10, 2 )

public function exibe_campo( $tag, $taxonomy ) {
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row">
            <label for="campo">Titulo do campo</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="campo" value="" />
            <p class="description">Descrição do campo</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

Não se esqueça de criar também uma função para salvar os seus campos, o WP não faz isso por padrão:

```
add_action( 'edited_terms', array( $this, 'salvar' ), 10, 2 );

public function salvar( $term_id, $taxonomy ) {
    $valor = $_POST['campo'];
    // valide permissões, nonces e outros parâmetros necessários aqui
    // e sanitize os dados antes de salvar

        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'term_meta_key', $valor );
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, ainda nao consegui. Sou iniciante em wordpress então meio que to batendo cabeça. Eu editei o edit-tags.php e add o seguinte trecho `<div class="form-field term-order-wrap">
 <label for="tag-order"><?php _e( 'Ordenação' ); ?></label>
 <input name="tag-order" id="tag-order" type="text" value="" size="40" aria-required="true" />
</div>` e já mostrou o campo. E no começo do arquivo está o `$ret = wp_insert_term( $_POST['tag-name'], $taxonomy, $_POST );` mas informação não está salvando

Comment: opa, opa, dê 2 passos pra trás. Você ** não pode ** editar o `edit-tags.php` em hipótese alguma. Senão quando o WordPress for atualizado vc vai perder tudo. Essas alterações tem que ir no seu tema ou plugin.

Comment: Aliás, não só o edit-tags: nunca edite NADA que esteja fora da pasta `wp-content`

Comment: Entendi, vou tentar editar o plugin, pelo que entendi a taxonomia foi declarada no plugin num arquivo que tem o mesmo nome do projeto/site

Comment: Uma pergunta, o objeto $this o que seria? O plugin onde é declarada a taxonomia não tem objetos e funções publicas e privadas

Comment: $this é quando isso está numa classe. Se é só um arquivo procedural vc pode trocar o array por uma string com o nome da função.

Comment: Consegui fazer aparecer o campo daquela forma no plugin, porém não consigo fazer salvar o valor do campo. A função que salva também vai no plugin?